# What words have “‑ei‑” (except in “‑cei‑”) pronounced [i:]?

Tags: orthography, writing, phonology, rules, mnemonic

The rule is that written *ei* is pronounced [i:] only after the letter *c* — or that what is pronounced [i:] is written *ei* after the letter *c* only.

Here are exceptions I’ve found so far:

- *foreign* (possibly)
- *seizure*
- *either* (possibly)
- *neither* (possibly)
- *weird*
- *being*
- *seizure*

Can you add more exceptions to this list?

---

**Update:**

I am not so much interested in differences of pronunciation between dialects of English as I am in helpful (for me) mnemonics for written English.

**Update 2:**

Once more, this question is not on orthography but on mnemonics to help in writing.

If you know other helpful mnemonics to deal with spelling words with *‑ie‑* and  *‑ei‑*, you are welcome to answer this question.

Comment: "ei" is not pronounced [i:] in _foreign_. I'm not sure if you're asking for exceptions to the "I before E, except after C" rule, but if you are, here's a link that may help: http://alt-usage-english.org/I_before_E.html

Comment: Seizure seizure? And I don't think "weird" and "being" fit?

Comment: It would be better to make clear to which English dialect you are referring; the pronunciation of _foreign_ in American English is different from the pronunciation in British English.

Comment: And "either" can have either [i:] or [aI]

Comment: I've never heard of that rule - only "I before E except after C", which has so many exceptions it's almost useless.

Comment: **foreign**, **weird** and **being** don't belong to your list.

Comment: What sound are you denoting "[i:]"?

Comment: @Martha: Assuming [i:] is written in standard IPA, [i] is the "ee" sound in "tree".

Comment: @Martha, the sound is always singular or mono-sound. For example most vowel letters in Russian consists of more than one mono-sound. For example to example, letter  "Я" is pronounced as composition of two sounds "i+a". And transcription, i.e. confinement in square parenthesis [  ], denotes mono-sounds.

Comment: @vgv8: My question was, are you using "[i:]" to mean the sound of ee as in tree, or i as in high? (Dunno what diphthongs have to do with anything here.)

Comment: @Martha, "[i:]" means the mono-sound of ee as in "tree". The letter "i" pronounced as two sounds in in the word "high"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user4729 mentioned, *caffeine* and *codeine*.  Another common word in that vaguely chemical vein would be *protein*.

I would also add *keister*, *leisure*, and *obeisance*.

Words that are less clear to me (because the overabundance of vowels makes it ambiguous to me whether the "-ei-" should be treated as a unit), are *onomatopoeia* and *plebeian*.  (I am leaning toward these being not good examples; but surely they are better than *being*, which is on the asker's list as I write this.)

Comment: It's kind of entertaining that you used the word *vein* in there.

Comment: It seems to me that "keister", "leisure" and "obeisance" are not pronounced as [i:]?

Comment: @Jon Purdy:  I realized I put that in my answer, but I didn't use it as an example because it doesn't satisfy the pronunciation requirement.

Comment: @vgv8: It depends... all three words *can* be pronounced correctly with [i:]. In the UK, though, "leisure" rhymes with "pleasure", the "ei" in "obeisance" is the vowel in "play", and we don't use the word "keister" at all :-)

Answer (score 3):

The rules of English orthography:

1. The first rule of English orthography is, you do not talk about rules in English orthography.
2. The second rule of English orthography is, you DO NOT talk about rules English orthography.
3. Two letters can be used for one sound.
4. Sometimes three (or more).
5. No real phonetics, no logic.
6. Words will go on as long as they have to.
7. If this is your first encounter with English orthography, you have to fight.

*(Loosely based on the rules of Fight Club)*

Comment: English has so many exceptions to its many rules, that they're almost useless. Further complications arise from differences in the several dialects making most rules specific for one dialect. English never had or has a language council to tidy up the mess.

Answer (score 1):

"Caffeine," "codeine," and many similar chemical names are exceptions also.

If you want a list of these, go to a crossword puzzle site like oneacross.com, and put in "???eine" for the pattern, with no clue, and you will get a list of words with the number of letters specified.

Comment: And how do I restrict the query by those "ei" pronounced as [i:]?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old post, but it distracted me from actually meeting my deadline.

For spelling lists with a relatively limited number of words that contain the spelling/sound combination, creating a silly sentence or two that contains them is the easiest for me.

"The seizure of the caffeine and codeine was neither weird nor leisurely. Either sitting on your keister or paying obeisance will tell anyone that!"

I left out foreign, because I have never heard it pronounced with a long ee sound, whereas I have heard either/neither pronounced with both long ee and i-e sounds.